# Is it possible to keep images in configuration document in lotus notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to keep image in configuration document, in order to change the image dynamically i am not able to do like that.or Is there any other way to keep images in forms or pages without entering into code everytime?

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to do, and what you have tried. Also, are you building an application for the Notes client, or for a web browser? What version of Lotus Notes, Domino and Domino Designer are you using?

Comment: If I would write an answer, then it would be "Yes there is even more than one way to do this". Richard is right: Tell us more and show what you tried, then we can probably help you

Comment: I am building notes client application. instead of opening designer and changing the image, I want to make it to change dynamically without opening the designer. Please suggest me the ways to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to dynamically change/replace the Image in the form/Page design element without using the notes designer.

In Notes, all Design elements are treated as a document and each design element have a unique  UNID. The "$Body" field stores the content of the form or page

You could do this by taking the UNID of the page or form and use db.GetDocumentByUNID() method to get handle to the Page or Form design element. Then modify the content of "$Body" field in lotus script to update image or any other data (table/text) in the Form/page. The changes will reflect in the Form/Page.

The UNID of the Page/form can be found in notes designer.

Let me know if this helps.